# Spring Async Executor : remove from queue after x time

Tags: java, executor, spring-async

I have an `Executor` defined here:

```
@Bean("asyncExecutor")
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolCorePoolSize());
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolMaxPoolSize());
    executor.setQueueCapacity(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolQueueCapacity());
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

I would like to be able to remove the tasks which stays more than X minutes in the queue (not being processed for X minutes)

Is there a simple way to do that? I could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in a custom class that will schedule the verification of the task status and will cancel it if it's not done.

```
public class CancellingExecutor implements Executor {

  private final ExecutorService delegate;
  private final ScheduledExecutorService monitoringExecutor;

  public CancellingExecutor(final ExecutorService delegate,
      final ScheduledExecutorService monitoringExecutor) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.monitoringExecutor = monitoringExecutor;
  }

  @Override
  public void execute(final Runnable command) {
    Future<?> future = delegate.submit(command);
    monitoringExecutor.schedule(() -> {
      if (!future.isDone() && !future.isCancelled()) {
        future.cancel(false);
      }
    }, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }
}
```

Configuration will look as follows:

```
@Bean("asyncExecutor")
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolCorePoolSize());
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolMaxPoolSize());
    executor.setQueueCapacity(appConfigProperties.getThreadpoolQueueCapacity());
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor-");
    executor.initialize();
    ScheduledExecutorService monitoringExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    return new CancellingExecutor(executor, monitoringExecutor);
}
```

Comment: It seems that your solution solves a different issue, which is being able to **cancel a running task**. What I am looking for is to remove from the **queue**, which means those tasks have never been executed yet.